# Removing items from a List without losing original reference - logic issue

Tags: c#

`myModelList` is a `List<MyModel>` object. `MyModel` consist of the following elements.

**MyModel**

```
public bool Name{ get; set; }
public bool Age { get; set; }
public List<School> SchoolsAttended{ get; set; }
```

So basically, I have a list of Object (*myModelList*) that contains a List of object (*SchoolsAttended*).

In `myModelList` object there are 2 elements of `SchoolsAttended` and in the `removeSchool` method I am removing the first element as shown in the code. Upto now, everything works as expected.

However, when the `foreach` loop goes through its 2nd iteration, the `SchoolsAttended` object only has 1 element in it. (this is because we removed an element in the previous iteration).

My question is, I need to maintain the same copy of `myModelList` in the main method, despite removing an object from the `removeSchool`.

In other words, It should not change the values in the original object which is `myModelList`.

**Main method**

```
foreach(var l in myModelList)
{
   removeSchool(l.SchoolsAttended);
}
```

**Remove method**

```
public void removeSchool(List<School> school) {
    school.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you use a logic like school NOT attended. This would mean it is more likely that the student did attend all schools? I still would go with logic to add schools they attended because it is a different list. Second option is copy list and remove.

Comment: Its a relationship between Student and School. A student attended  many schools. Name, Age, and SchoolsAttended belong to the Student Model (in this case its MyModel)

Comment: I understand the relation, but in your Model there are all schools (as I understood). I got the impression you worked with a kind of template for all the schools and used this on all students. Maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<School>` is a reference type instance When you use `school.RemoveAt(0);` that will remove the first item from `school`

If you want to keep the original data, you can try to use linq `Where` seconde override method to make you expect.

> public static IEnumerable Where(this `IEnumerable<TSource>`source, `Func<TSource, bool>` predicate);

The second parameter is your index in your collection.

```
foreach(var l in myModelList)
{
   l.SchoolsAttended = l.SchoolsAttended.Where((k, idx) => idx > 0).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What will be the predicate be like ? I didn't understand the `Where` part of the code. Could be please help me out ?

Comment: linq `Where` will filter the collection which satisfies your condition.   http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-where-operator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep original `myModelList` you can create its copy:

```
var myModelList = /* your data here */
var copy = myModelList.Select(m => new MyModel
{
    Name = m.Name,
    Age = m.Age,
    SchoolsAttended = m.SchoolsAttended.Skip(1).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

`Skip` method will remove first School from `SchoolsAttended`

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why both items of `myModelList` reference the same `List<School>` object.
I suggest that you ensure that all `MyModel` instances use different lists.
To that end, you can add an initializer to `SchoolsAttended` and make the property readonly:

```
public List<School> SchoolsAttended{ get; private set; } = new List<School>();
```

When creating your model you can call `AddRange` to fill the list, e.g.:

```
model.SchoolsAttended.AddRange(otherModel.SchoolsAttended);
```